# Java class to XSD

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

Could someone please tell me what XSD matches this Java class?

```
public class MyClass {

    private List<String> list1;

    private List<String> list2;

    private XMLGregorianCalendar date;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I've tried the following, but I'm receiving an *One of :attribute, :attributeGroup, :anyAttribute is expected* error:

```
<xs:element name="myClass">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="list1" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="list2" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="date" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So it seems I'm not using the `<xs:sequence>` tag correctly. Could someone please shed some light? (I'm far from being an expert in XML-related stuff)...

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE version with Java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xs:sequence` within a `xs:complexType` defines a specific order in which an elements children must occur. To create a list of elements you simply use the `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` directly on the `xs:element` tag you want repeated, as follows:

```
<xs:element name="myClass">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="list1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="list2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="date" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This should create the class you expect and require XML such as the following (order of tags matter):

```
<myClass>
  <list1>a</list1>
  <list1>b</list1>
  <list2>y</list2>
  <list2>z</list2>
  <date>2019-06-26T00:00:00.0000000Z</date>
</myClass>
```

Placing `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` on the `xs:sequence` tag requires the entire sequence of elements to be repeated.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for